# PayPal donation form not working in WordPress

Tags: html, html-table, paypal, html-select

This form was copied directly from WordPress so the button won't work.
What I want to ask is it used to take users directly to the page that charges the amount they selected, but now it just sends them to the default PayPal login page. I would like to find out if something got messed up in the code. Is there a way to find out?

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<h1> </h1>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 36pt;"><strong><span style="font-family: Roboto;">PayPal Monthly Donation</span></strong></span></h1>
<table class=" aligncenter" style="border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 58px;" width="848">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border: none;"><input name="on0" type="hidden" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: none;">
<p><select name="os0">
<option value="Opt10">$10.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Opt20">$20.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Opt30">$30.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Opt50">$50.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Opt100">$100.00 USD - monthly</option>
</select></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" height="50px" name="submit" src="https://www.jtsamerica.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/DONATE-BUTTON.jpg" type="image" width="160" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look messed up, for various reasons. You should generate new, proper button code.  https://www.paypal.com/buttons is one of the places you can do so

Once you have new code, use it somewhere that accepts raw HTML, and won't mangle it. There are very many Wordpress plugins for this.